# Using the notification inbox as an... actual inbox?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, notifications

I think it would be nice if, for our notification inbox, we could delete notifications after we've read them. Just for organizational purposes. (And if that gets added, perhaps the filter by date function could be removed for it.)

Comment: Related: [Feed for global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66728/feed-for-global-inbox)

Comment: @Kevin hey, can you please explain why this feature request has been declined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I approve of this suggestion because I would really like to be able to manage what I do at *work* separately from what I do at *home*. I'm happy to deal with [SO](http://stackoverflow.com), [P.SX](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) and other work related SX sites at work, but many other SX sites are just for personal interest and it wouldn't be appropriate to deal with them on *work time*.

I would love it if Inbox notifications were only 'marked as read' when I actually clicked on them. At the moment, if you click on any of the Inbox items, they *all* stop being highlighted (are marked as Read in UX terms).

That way I would be able to ignore non-work related notifications during the day, and have all my non work notifications still highlighted when I get home. Similarly, while at home I could ignore work related notifications, and have them all still highlighted when I get to work the next day.

Answer (score 2):

workaround: You can use the RSS-feed of a question instead of using the star, and your favourite RSS-reader will certainly have this feature

Comment: Did you bump this question down one or was that someone else? I don't want to download an RSS feeder, then subscribe manually to each and every question I reply to, whereas this idea could just be implemented :S

Comment: @TGP1994: in fact I +1'ed you, and as I mentioned this answer would only be a work-around. I don't -1 without comments usually.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much then :) I apologize if I came at a bad angle there. I wish that the -1 person explains why they think it's bad.

Comment: @TGP1994: I guess they want to state something like "I don't think this is important enough to take the developers time"

Comment: @TGP Meta works differently than SO in terms of downvotes. A downvote here is a mere sign of disagreement, it's not necessarily an indication that something is wrong with your question or answer. It's closer to an actual *voting* process - "do you want this, or not"?

Comment: Actually, one should then better use the *responses* feed rather than a *question* feed. One other advantage: it shows a much longer summary, not just the first few characters. See your user profile, tab Responses, bottom right corner, @TGP.