# Feed for global inbox

Tags: feature-request, feed, global-inbox

When I'm active, I'm often participating in multiple questions and even different SE sites.  I find myself refreshing random pages just to see if there's new items in the global inbox.  If these notifications were available as an RSS or Atom feed, I could easily use various desktop/dockbar/browser/etc. widgets to ping me.

Could we get a feed for the global inbox?

Comment: Possibly related? [Poll in background for StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ inbox events and update the titlebar accordingly à la Facebook](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66712/poll-in-background-for-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-inbox-events-a)

Comment: @Marko: Related, but I'd still get more use out of a feed I can plug into any of several utilities I use now.

Comment: +1 - I agree 100%, it would certainly be useful.

Answer (score 7):

Lacking such a feed, I've been abusing https://stackoverflow.com/inbox when I want a page I can just refresh; it's intended to help with debugging the inbox but it's a quick way to see if anything has changed. There's also the [JSON version](https://stackoverflow.com/inbox/genuwine) that actually powers the inbox, so you could wrap that in a script

Comment: *Nice!* I wasn't aware that existed; if it didn't require a login cookie, it'd be easy to wrap into a feed.

Comment: @Roger It's sort of undocumented, like /reputation. Accessing the JSON version will even mark all the new posts as read (the HTML version won't), since that's how the real inbox does things, but the login cookie part is a bit of a problem

Comment: There is such a feed. See my answer below.

Comment: It seems http://stackoverflow.com/inbox is deprecated. The JSON version is still there though.

Comment: The JSON version is no longer there, either. Saddest day. ;_;

Answer (score 4):

This is easy to answer - I wrote a small application that does exactly that. It's called [Stack2RSS](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service-now-with-a-feed-browser-and-email-s) and you can use it by visiting [this](http://quickmediasolutions.com/stackmail/) page.

The URL for the feed you'd want is as follows:

> `http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/{$site}/users/{$user_id}/mentioned`

Where `$site` is the domain name of the site you're interested in and `$user_id` is your user ID for that site. (You can find this by visting your profile page and looking at the URL.)

For example, an RSS feed for replies to you on Meta (right here), you would use:

> http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/meta.stackoverflow/users/54262/mentioned

Comment: That is site-specific, the global inbox is not.

Comment: @Roger: You mean you couldn't use multiple feeds? Maybe I'll have to add that ability to Stack2RSS - you're not the first to request it :)

Comment: I'd prefer a single feed instead of 20, yes. :)

Comment: @Gnome: You can merge several fields into one using Yahoo! Pipes

Comment: That will require listing each feed - rather laborious.