# A way to access the SE Global Inbox from Chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, global-inbox

**Related:** [Feed for global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66728/feed-for-global-inbox)

---

I spend a lot of time in chat these days, and only pop over to a site when I have a question, or see something in the feed reader that I want to answer.  This sometimes causes my inbox to have lots of replys that I would have liked to see earlier.  I don't usually pop out of the chat screen, using the handy sidebar to navigate to different rooms.

**Please add a way to access the SE Global Inbox from the chat screen.**

Comment: Came to meta to post this, found this.  I completely agree that this would be awesome to have.

Comment: Popped over to suggest this exactly, and found it already existing.  It's a great idea and I'd love to see a *lot* more support for it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please bring the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ to the chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69306/please-bring-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-to-the-chat)

Comment: @TomWijsman I'd say the main difference is that I don't want it to refresh, at least not nearly that often.  Once an hour would be Ok.

Comment: @CRoss: Isn't your mail inbox sufficient for this? You can let it mail inbox messages in a 3 hours interval.

Comment: @TomWijsman I'd rather not get yet another e-mail (or five to ten) every day.

Comment: I would like to register my support for this as well, if for nothing more than to bump it.

Comment: Really? Still nothing?

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, if you wish to have this a bit more integrated with the chat interface, you might be interested in:

[ChatterBox - user script that adds inbox integration to Stack Exchange Chat!](https://stackapps.com/questions/2985/chatterbox-userscript-that-adds-inbox-integration-to-stackexchange-chat)

[image]

This screenshot is slightly out of date, as it now also displays the item body.

Answer (score 5):

With the advent of [API 2.0](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-no-longer-beta/) we can all use [George Edison](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142114/)'s [StackAlert](https://stackapps.com/questions/2909/stack-alert-mozilla-firefox-add-on-keep-tabs-on-your-inbox-without-needing-t) app to watch the inbox while we're in chat.  I know I am!

Answer (score 4):

I also recently made a userscript that can help here, it adds a [full top bar to chat rooms](https://stackapps.com/questions/7404/top-bar-for-chat-rooms):

[image]

With realtime notifications and functional dropdowns:

[image]

And optional chat theme matching:

[image]

Answer (score -12):

There already is a way to access global inbox from chat; the global inbox is accessible from all non-chatroom pages in chat:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeff, but I really don't spend much time on the non-chatroom pages in chat.  I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: That doesn't help when I'm in a chatroom, and I'd still have to refresh it frequently.