# Please bring the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ to the chat

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat, information-display, stack-exchange-button

This would be useful to have next to the all rooms button.

Perhaps let it refresh each 30 or 60 seconds... :-)

Comment: @MarcGravell: Oh cool, thanks! :-)

Comment: by way of explanation; we plan on bringing it *into the chat system*, but not inside the actual live chat window. My bad for misreading the question.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I'm confused about what you mean by "chat system". It's already there at the top of http://chat.stackexchange.com/, or did you just implement it there? Well, what about adding a non-refreshing version which you can only refresh by refreshing the whole page, by switching rooms or by means of a small refresh button?

Comment: That went in today (or yesterday at earliest).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those of you still following this, you might be interested in the answers to this question:

[A way to access the SE Global Inbox from Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67264/a-way-to-access-the-se-global-inbox-from-chat)

There are a couple of suggestions that might be of use.

Comment: The user script basically does what I want, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

30 or 60 seconds is IMO *way* too often for something that *by definition* is data you aren't avidly watching at that moment. Even 5 minutes seems overly aggressive. It has come up before, though, and was deferred. I'll ask around, to see if that has changed...

Comment: 10 minutes or more for the hot questions could do, but the point in doing it more than that is that you could have a visual (red number for inbox) and audio notification (new inbox item) for new comments, answers or answers in chat rooms you are not in at the moment. My focus lies on the inbox in this request.

Comment: @TomWij - re chat rooms; that is perhaps better addressed separately. We actually *deliberately* delay delivery of chat messages to the MultiCollider, to reduce filling the inbox with things that we think you have seen. I think the thing to focus on, then, is what you want to see...? and when?

Comment: On each refresh, check when the user last visited the chat room or site and if that visit is older than a predetermined time, then: Check for new answers or comments and inform the user as described above with an audio-visual notification, similar to the current one here but then accompanied with a sound.

Comment: Perhaps the refresh rate can be determined based on how popular the user is; I would consider the refresh rate for a new user to be different from the refresh rate a high rep user, a moderator or Jeff Atwood needs.

Comment: @Tom you may find this useful: http://stackapps.com/questions/1703/so-live-live-updates-to-your-reputation-score

Comment: Hmm, haven't thought of writing an extension. I'll wait to see if others have interest.