# Add new top bar to chat rooms

Tags: feature-request, chat, top-bar

Now that we have a shiny new top bar, have there been any changes in plans to make it visible in the chat rooms? The responses in old threads I've found seem to defer or decline the option due to issues which may have been resolved by now, completely side-step the problem, or refer to third-party solutions.

[A way to access the SE Global Inbox from Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67264/152399)

- Some third-party solutions and a non-answer that addresses the chat index, but not chat rooms.

[Please bring the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ to the chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69306/152399)

- Acceptance of the general concept seems unconfirmed. *"It has come up before, though, and was deferred. I'll ask around, to see if that has changed..."* Based on that same answer, it appears this request was rejected because the suggested refresh rate was too often. The new top bar automatically updates, so this should no longer be an issue.

I'm interested to find out what the current status is with regards to implementing this directly on the SE chatrooms, without the need for client-side plugins or scripts.

Comment: I [believe this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign#comment629980_198613) will happen eventually, but a timeframe would be nice.

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks. It would be good to have that answer here, along with the appropriate status tag, from SEI so that this will be more visible to others looking for the feature.

Comment: Probably the same reason as [Why is the top bar not changed on StackExchange, Area51 and Ask Ubuntu?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210357/why-is-the-top-bar-not-changed-on-stackexchange-area51-and-ask-ubuntu).

Comment: @animuson Quite possibly indeed, but that's not an easy assumption. Without having seen the comment bluefeet pointed out, I had no indication that SEI was presently considering this feature at all. The thread you link is asking about updating a feature that already exists on the target pages. Mine's about adding that feature where it does not yet exist at all.

Comment: ITYM an ugly new top bar? What's the use of it in chat?

Comment: Opinions aside, its use would be the same as on any other site - monitoring of activity on your reputation, questions, and answers from across the network.

Comment: @Gilles IMO, it would be great to see notifications (inbox especially) when you are in a chat window.  Right now, you have to go to a different tab to see if you have any notices.  We asked for this functionality over on [DBA.SE](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/907/chat-and-the-se-toolbar) a while ago.

Comment: I would just like to know where my link to chat went in the top bar.  I have had to make a bookmark for chat now :(

Comment: @DaImTo See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210187/152399).

Comment: @iszi thanks i knew it had to be there some place.