# Change Chat dropdown in top bar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, top-bar

In the [**all rooms** page](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms) of *chat* we still have the old StackExchange dropdown:

[image: Chat All Rooms Dropdown]

Could we please have the new dropdown installed there?

Comment: Related, but for regular chat rooms: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211144/add-new-top-bar-to-chat-rooms?rq=1

Comment: Appears to be fixed now.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, thanks, I've flagged the mods to mark it 'status-completed'.

Comment: Already did that. :-) Oddly, I can't find any kind of announcement about this. Maybe it'll show up in [recent changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) at some point.