# Add "notifications" tab to global inbox in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications, global-inbox

It appears that the "notifications" tab has been rolled out for all sites, similar to how the regular inbox is. From the [blog post announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications):

> Notifications are now:

> - global: get a badge on Stack Overflow and you’ll see the notice on Gaming

Can the notifications tab be added to chat's global inbox? (Not inside an actual chat room, mind you, where there is no inbox at all, but in https://chat.stackexchange.com/ for example, where there is).

---

Here's some screenshots to illustrate the issue:

[image: Dropdown from https://chat.stackexchange.com/.]

For comparison, the dropdown usually looks like this:

[image: "Normal" dropdown.]

Note that "email settings" is also missing from the box on https://chat.stackexchange.com/.  My guess is that we are looking at an outdated version of the "global" inbox on that page.

---

Unrelated: [A way to access the SE Global Inbox from Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67264/168660)

Comment: To answer your bounty message, @Jon, it's neither an oversight nor by design. Just a bit low-priority. Anything global inbox-y is a bit more complicated on chat than on the other sites, because the route to the data is longer.

Comment: @balpha: Got it.  It's also kinda minor in the grand scheme of things.  It took me a month and a half longer than it took HodofHod to notice it.  Thanks for the response though it sounds like this won't change anytime soon.

Comment: @balpha So [tag:status-deferred]?

Comment: Since the UI for the inbox dropdown has changed since this request was made, there's no separate "notifications" vs. "inbox" tab. As such, I'm closing this request as no longer reproducible.