# How do we see the private messages that moderators sent us?

Tags: support, global-inbox, moderator-messages

I've got a message sent to me from a moderator which appears in the top-left notification dropdown box.

Clicking on the "item" brings me to a page where the message is shown. But after reading it I've closed the browser tab.

How can I get to the message page again?

Answer (score 9):

The notification bar that told you about the message contained a link to it. You also usually get an e-mail about it, and the e-mail will have a link (it should point to stackoverflow.com/users/message/#)

Comment: i definitely had the link in the notification bar (if you mean the bar at the top of the page) but of course its not there anymore..

Comment: the email give me a link: http://stackoverflow.com/users/message/544 which is working. So am i expected to keep that mail in my inbox for as long as I'd wish to "go back to that page next time"?

Comment: What about the SE global inbox?

Comment: @random nop.. it only shows the activities of the threads.. i.e. replies and comments

Comment: So there's no special way to see it without having to go to our email or notifications?

Comment: @puretppc: the global inbox [does show](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222812/150034) moderator messages.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Yeah but it's gonna be hard digging through lots of activity especially users who are very active

Comment: @puretppc: trues. You can vote on [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63939/using-the-notification-inbox-as-an-actual-inbox) to implement inbox filters.

Answer (score 6):

As of Feb 2014, you can see moderator messages in the global StackExchange inbox, if you scroll down to the "more inbox messages..." link:

[image: StackExchange inbox]

Once in the inbox though, there's [no way to filter for "moderator message"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63939/using-the-notification-inbox-as-an-actual-inbox). You'll have to go through the paging buttons and maybe try to aim for the point in time at which you remember receiving the message. That might be difficult because [the year is not displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222811/display-year-in-the-inbox-message-date-stamp).

Here's my Inbox:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore. Do you still see the "moderator" messages in the global inbox?