# Change account from one StackExchange OpenID to another

Tags: support, bug, stack-exchange-openid, multiple-accounts

I would like to split my accounts on the different StackExchange sites professional and personal ones. I plan to only use one account per site.

At the moment all my StackExchange accounts are connected with one StackExchange OpenID and an old myOpenID OpenID.

I read [Is it possible to separate professional Stack Exchange accounts from personal ones?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98428/is-it-possible-to-separate-professional-stack-exchange-accounts-from-personal-on) and [What are the possible alternatives to maintain separate accounts for the 'Workplace' and 'Personal Productivity' sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179007/what-are-the-possible-alternatives-to-maintain-separate-accounts-for-the-workpl?rq=1) and understood, that I can split off the personal accounts if I associate them with another StackExchange OpenID.

Here is what I have tried, which did not work:

1. Logged out of my old Stackexchange OpenID
2. Made sure I am still logged in with my myOpenID OpenID
3. Created a second SE OpenID with another e-mail address
4. Went to my userpage on one of the subsites and removed the SE OpenID via `my logins`
5. Clicked on `add more logins`, `log in with StackEchange` and `Confirm New Login` to add my new SE OpenID with the new email address

Then I clicked again `my logins`, but the new SE OpenID was not added.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It's too bad this didn't get answered... I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked again and all my accounts now have the two StackExchange OpenIDs connected with them.

If it was only a display bug or if a mod fixed this I cannot say.